# Public methods using prototype with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to create public and private methods for javascript functions with return statements.

I like the idea of using return to pass back the publicly accessible methods because it easy to see all of your public properties and methods in one place.

```
var Base = function(){
  var method1 = function(){
    console.log("method1");
  }
  var method2 = function(){
    console.log("method2");
  }
  //private
  var method3 = function(){
    console.log("method3");
  }
  // public methods
  return {
    method1:method1,
    method2:method2
  }
}
var Child = function(){
  var method4 = function(){
    console.log("method4");
  }
  var method5 = function(){
    console.log("method5");
  }
  //private
  var method6 = function(){
    console.log("method6");
  }
  // public methods
  return {
    method4:method4,
    method5:method5

  }
}
Child.prototype = new Base();

var base = new Base();
base.method1();
base.method2();

var child = new Child();
try {
  child.method1();
} catch(e){
  console.log(e.message);
}
try {
  child.method2();
} catch(e){
  console.log(e.message);
}
child.method4();
child.method5();
```

I know if I do it like this I will get the public/private methods, but I was wondering if anyone knew how to do it with the return statement.

```
var Base = function(){
  // public methods
  this.method1 = function(){
    console.log("method1");
  };
  this.method2 = function(){
    console.log("method2");
  };
  // private methods
  var method3 = function(){
    console.log("method2");
  };
};
var Child = function(){
  // public methods
  this.method4 = function(){
    console.log("method4");
  };
  this.method5 = function(){
    console.log("method5");
  };
  // private methods
  var method6 = function(){
    console.log("method6");
  };
};
Child.prototype = new Base();

var base = new Base();
base.method1();
base.method2();

var child = new Child();
child.method1();
child.method2();
child.method4();
child.method5();
```

Comment: there is no such thing as a private method in javascript. it's an inherent contradiction because if it's a method, it's not private; it's a property of the object as seen by all.

Comment: Have a look at the following answer, it may help. First it'll explain why setting prototype of Child to an instance of Parent shows a lack of understanding of the role of the constructor function and the prototype and it covers private functions (shared on prototype) as well as a pattern for instance specific "protected" members http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You must not use `return` if you want to use prototypical inheritance, you should use `this` as it is the instance object that inherits from your prototype.

Of course, nothing prevents you from congregating your public interface in the end of the constructor:

```
function Base() {
  function method1() {
    console.log("method1");
  }
  function method2() {
    console.log("method2");
  }
  //private
  function method3() {
    console.log("method3");
  }
  // public methods
  this.method1 = method1;
  this.method2 = method2;
}
```

Notice that you [should not use `new Base` for the inheritance of `Child.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572).